# Respond to inputs in Python

Tags: python, function, input

I am trying to make a simple game for learning English grammar using Python. Basically, the user inputs the verb form and Python should return 'correct' or 'incorrect'. I am trying to do this using a function:

```
def simple_past():
    question1 = input('I ____ to the park. Input: ').lower()  
    if input == 'went':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')
```

But when I type in 'went', it always sends back 'incorrect'. My question is twofold: (1) why is it returning 'incorrect' even thought I am typing in 'went', (2) is this the best way to make this kind of activity? Cheers

Comment: `if question1 == 'went':` is what you should write

Comment: `input` is just a built-in Python function. In your second line you assign the return value of it to the variable `question1` and it is that which you should check if it is `== 'went'`

Answer (score 3):

```
def simple_past():
    question1 = input('I ____ to the park. Input: ').lower()  
    if question1 == 'went':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')
```

Value from input will be stored in the `question1` variable. So you should be comparing `question1` and `'went'`

Answer (score 0):

That is the reason we should give meaningful names to variables.

```
def simple_past():
    input_value = input('I ____ to the park. Input: ').lower()  
    if input_value == 'went':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')
```